# Reason for not being able to convert wsdl to java class using intellij

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl

Hello friends and thanks in advance for your time and attention.
I've consumed from lots of web services till now but I could barely use intellij built in tool to convert wsdl to java classes. It faces an error about duplicate id(s). So if converting web service code to wsdl is done by means of a tool just like Intellij tool , why it's not working properly reversing the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven and using the org.apache.cxf plugin, you can set autoNameResolution to true, which solves the problem for duplicate IDs

```
<configuration>
    <defaultOptions>                                
        <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
    </defaultOptions>
</configuration>
```